# List with views stacked on top of each other

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

You usually traverse a list by scrolling through the views that are placed one after another. What I'm trying to achieve is similar, but the views would be stacked on top of each other. The views will also cover the whole screen. So when you scroll, the top view slides away (or uses some other transition animation), but the bottom one is not moving underneath. You can imagine that the views are like the papers in a top spiral-bound notebook.

So my question is - does something similar already exist? I haven't been able to found anything so I might need to make a custom implementation. Oh and the views will each contain an image and there might be quite a few of them, so it will need to handle that (I was thinking of using [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)). Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea how you can do that. Might be fairly complex, but great choice for the image loading library !

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @fifth We decided to use custom implementation of a sidescrolling parallax viewpager instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use Depth page transformer, via http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer

Comment: It's not quite what I'm looking for, but it might prove to be useful. I'll look into it, thanks.